# How to exclude first and second minus character from the right?

Tags: regex

I've this  list above I'm working a REGEX on  https://regex101.com/

```
BETA - Asia-926-5.6.6
BETA - Asia-926-5.5.7
BETA - AU-843-5.6.6
BETA - AU-843-5.5.7
BETA - East-Europe-500-5.6.6
BETA - East-Europe-500-5.5.7
```

I found this REGEX `[^0-9,.]` to exclude all digits and point but I don't how to exclude the first and second minus character from the right for get something like this :

```
BETA - Asia
BETA - Asia
BETA - AU
BETA - AU
BETA - East-Europe
BETA - East-Europe
```

Comment: You could match what you want to delete `-\d+-\d+(?:\.\d+)+$` and replace with an empty string https://regex101.com/r/7IJuXb/1

Comment: A more generic solution matching your title requirement is `(?:-[^-]*){2}$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/0WZ9h6/3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match the last 2 hyphens and the pattern for the digits, and replace the match with an empty string.

```
-\d+-\d+(?:\.\d+)+$
```

- `-\d+-` Match `-`, 1+ digits and `-`
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)+` Match 1+ times a dot and 1+ digits
- `$` End of string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7IJuXb/1/)

Output

```
BETA - Asia
BETA - Asia
BETA - AU
BETA - AU
BETA - East-Europe
BETA - East-Europe
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match all text beginning with the last but one hyphen using

```
(?:-[^-]*){2}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0WZ9h6/3)

**Details**

- `(?:-[^-]*){2}` - two occurrences (`{2}`) of

  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `[^-]*` - 0 or more chars other than `-`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple regex to remove a dash, followed by number, and all remaining characters:

```js
var strings = [
  'BETA - Asia-926-5.6.6',
  'BETA - Asia-926-5.5.7',
  'BETA - AU-843-5.6.6',
  'BETA - AU-843-5.5.7',
  'BETA - East-Europe-500-5.6.6',
  'BETA - East-Europe-500-5.5.7'
];
var regex = /\-[0-9].*$/;
strings.forEach(function(str) {
  var result = str.replace(regex, '')
  console.log(str + ' ==> ' + result);
});
```

Output:

```
BETA - Asia-926-5.6.6 ==> BETA - Asia
BETA - Asia-926-5.5.7 ==> BETA - Asia
BETA - AU-843-5.6.6 ==> BETA - AU
BETA - AU-843-5.5.7 ==> BETA - AU
BETA - East-Europe-500-5.6.6 ==> BETA - East-Europe
BETA - East-Europe-500-5.5.7 ==> BETA - East-Europe
```

Explanation of regex:

- `\-` - a literal dash
- `[0-9]` - a digit
- `.*$` - everything to end

The replacement part is empty, hence it will remove the match.